# How to bind ESA ID to MDM using .net library

Tags: google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to use Google Play EMM API for binding ESA to MDM (enrollment of customer) using .net Client libraries. but i am unable to get any clue to how to do this? I tried to use given Samples but no luck still.

Is there any method(s) or documentation available in .net library which helps to resolve this issue?

service object which contains ESA ID .Enterprise

```
enterprise = new Enterprise(); 
enterprise.PrimaryDomain = primaryDomainName;
EnterprisesResource obj = new EnterprisesResource(service);
Enterprise result = obj.Enroll(enterprise, authenticationToken).Execute();
```

Comment: First where did you find the nugget package from Google Play EMM API.   Second can you post an example of your code that you are having issues. with.

Comment: Install a NuGet package from those available at Google.Apis.androidenterprise. and code as follows

Comment: In this code i am unable to create service object which contains ESA ID .Enterprise enterprise = new Enterprise(); enterprise.PrimaryDomain = primaryDomainName;EnterprisesResource obj = new EnterprisesResource(service);
                Enterprise result = obj.Enroll(enterprise, authenticationToken).Execute();

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=Google.Apis.androidenterprise&prerelease=true&sortOrder=relevance

Comment: is there any solution or guidence available regarding it?